# linking/syncing the chat application on a website to android

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, web

Can anyone point me to a tutorial that can show me how to be able to chat with customers that make queries from a web chat on my mobile? I have been searching and I cant find one. I would like to use javascript and jquery if possible so that I can be able to plug it into all our sites no matter which language they were developed in .

So in summary if a user sends a message on anyone of our websites I want to be able to reply them on my phone if I am not in my office

Answer (score 0):

Read about Firebase. You can build a web-app and android client connected to the firebase messaging.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-firebase-chat/#0

Comment: Thanks I am having a look at those links will give feedback

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, i also wanted to attempt that, my solution was the use sockets. try socket.io it aims to make real time apps possible in every browser and mobile device. However i only tested it on a android device.

try this library: `https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java`

Comment: You could also use google firebase cloud messaging but it is more mobile to mobile approach but websites are gladly accepted as well.